# Which C# method of manipulating ms-access should a experienced DBA use?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to write a Windows Form application to interact with an ms-Access DB.  I'm fairly well versed in SQL (DB2 and T-SQL), and in C# - but not together.

Should I use the support in VS-2019 for Table adapters and data bindings?  Or should I code my own SQLCommands thru an OLEDB connection?  Which will get me done faster?  Which will cause me less frustration?

I often get frustrated with WYSIWYG, and have had problems using some built in DataSet type interfaces in the past (8ish years ago).  At the moment, I'm doing the entry/retrieval in ms-access natively - but that's getting old.  But I rarely use it's WYSIWYG stuff - I usually just write my own query.

I've got the ms-access DB fairly well normalized - good breakdown of primary and foreign keys, etc.  The larger tables are up to about 1000 rows - and will stay roughly there for a while - some slow growth.  The data is keeping track of our customers and the classes they and their children are taking.  The data has personal demographics, plus a list of class offerings, and the enrollments in each - both current and historical.

At some point, I hope to move the application into a web-based implementation, hitting a hosted SQL DB instead - so we can interface with it anywhere.  But that's too much to learn right now.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see the difference if you using the oleDB provider for SQL server, Oracle, or ms-access.

Those providers once chosen pull data equally well in to a a datatable, dataset, and darn near all of the .net ojbects. In other words, it not a big concern that you use the ODBC driver to SQL server, or the now (and being depreciated oleDB choice). Or you use the sqlprovder.

All of these providers as I noted will work with and pull data into the standard set of object (sqlcommand, datatable etc.).

So, the choice of which provider is rather neutral. Of course, for a desktop application (stand alone), then Access as a data engine choice is quite nice. For multi-user, of course then some free edition of SQL express is preferred.

The advantage of Access is some additional integration with say Excel, (the JET/ACE engine can read, and export to Excel.

However, if Access is as a reporting tool, or some existing desktop application you need to interact with - then of course using JET/ACE makes sense.

However, if you NOT use the Access UI and JUST the data engine? Well then then you are just choosing X data engine over Y data engine. So, sqlLite is also a nice "in process" stand alone data engine, and is file based like msaccess. So, as a file based stand alone "in-process", then JET/ACE or sqlLite are both great choices.

Keep in mind another strong reason to use the JET/ACE data engie is that a copy is installed by default on all copies of windows (been that way since the windows 98SE days).

However, if you choose the built in engine, then you can only use the mdb (older format) files. If you need some integreatio with say some existing Access application (and you not just need a data engine), then you have to use the newer ACE data engine to work with accDB file formats. So, if no interaction is required with MSAccess as a desktop application, and you JUST are needing a data engine then JET is fine as opposed to ACE (ACE is the newer Access data engine, and it is not installed on windows by default, but is installed with Access, or as a stand alone download)

The other considering is that JET is only available as a x32 bit version. So, your .net application will run "in process" as x32 as opposed to x64. If your .net code needs to interact with other x64 (non managed code) systems, then you can NOT use JET, but there is a x64 bit version of ACE available).

So, using Access, or Oracle don't make a difference here, you use the .net providers (oleDB, ODBC). But as noted, once you chosen those providers, they all work with the resulting .net objects such as tables, data sets etc.

One can make the case that if future considerations are sql server, then one could and should consider SQL express. However, a automatic install and setup of SQL express is a whole project to its own, and is a pain. Where as JET is already installed on windows - you don't have to do anything to use it - (don't even have to install it).

I have used both oleDB provder for Access, and the ODBC provider - not a big deal.

Comment: It's not the particular database that I'm trying to learn - I'm trying to decide the C# access method to use.
- I can use the Visual Studio's WYSIWYG stuff - with the quite nice relationship diagrams and data bindings - but then the SQL is hidden from me.  
- I can write my own SQL using the native objects - but then I have to track all the SQL and populate my windows on my own.
I'm not sure which will be faster - and easier in the long run.  I can't find anything listing a 'side by side comparison.

Comment: I am not aware that VS will do the relationships and diagrams for Access. You can use the table designer in VS, but other then that, I am not aware of VS being able to do this. You can certainly create a entity model - and you can use that for any database. However, in most cases, you likely just use a connection object. The table design tools will be in Access or SQL server or whatever system  you are using (in those other systems is where you create the tables, setup relationships etc.).  If  was say using Access, and then wanted same code for SQL server? I would use oleDB, or ODBC.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the builder to create a dataset. The sql for such datasets is viewable and can be modified. So your question is not what data provider system you should use (since they all much work the same), but your question is should I use the internal dataset builder when working with forms, or simply write out the sql "in-line". Well, the choice is really up to you. For a simple sql statement, I just type in the sql "in-line" right in the code. If the sql is complex, or I want to use say a bound forms control (or grid), then you are free to use the dataset wizard if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

From the, "Which will cause me less frustration" point of view, with the experience you listed and the final desire to move to a hosted SQL DB, such as Azure SQL Database (essentially SQL Server in the cloud) I would suggest your time best used exploring the option of going direct from Windows Forms to SQL Database in Azure.

Your data access technologies are essentially ADO.net, which it sounds like you have some experience in, that will likely include your various OLEDB connection technologies, and of course EF or Entity Framework.

I have been essentially in your situation several times with client Access DB's as the data store, the WYSIWYG or table adapters and the "easy linking of data" seem to always become a sticking point that eats time and can't be rolled forward when you move from Access.

Just my thoughts based on the range of questions and info you provided.

Comment: So - I should just move from Access to a hosted DB now?  That's not a bad idea.

Comment: Your asking for overall design advice which is hard for anyone to give a definitive answer. You asked a wide question, your going to have to accept a wide answer unless you get more specific. Based on your input, I would move toward the hosted SQL since you indicated that was your ultimate path. There are many ways to skin this cat, as Gustav above said, much is based on preference and experience.

Comment: I don't think I'm asking for 'overall design' - just whether I should use the built-in WYSIWYG stuff, or code my own SQL.
I've *tried* to find something that compares the pluses and minuses between the two (or if there's something else) - and there's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the support in VS-2019 for Table adapters and data
>   bindings? Or should I code my own SQLCommands thru an OLEDB
>   connection? Which will get me done faster? Which will cause me less
>   frustration?

I began using the DatabaseTableAdapters in VS2005 and haven't looked back. It's a pleasure to work with the strongly typed datatables and have the SQL stuffed away.

But you'll find many opinions on this, and it is highly a matter of preference and experience.